# Comparar fechas con LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

Buen día a todos. Tengo una consulta donde comparo las fechas de inicio y fin antes de guardar en la base de datos.

```
var r = from t1 in db.TblEtapa                                                                     
        where (fechaInicio >= t1.fecha_inicio && fechaFin <= t1.fecha_fin) select t1;
```

Si tengo guardado registros con las fechas:

```
      **fecha_inicio**  |  **fecha_fin**                                                                     
         2020-04-22     |    2020-04-28                                                         
         2020-04-29     |    2020-05-03
```

La consulta me devuelve un resultado si envío las fechas:

```
(2020-04-23 | 2020-04-27) o (2020-04-30 | 2020-04-02).
```

Como están dentro del rango no las guardo en la base de datos. Pero si envío:

```
(2020-04-23 | 2020-04-30).
```

¿Cómo podría hacer la consulta para validar esa parte?

Comment: `Pero si envío: (2020-04-23 | 2020-04-30).` Qué pasa?

Comment: @Lobos No retornaría un resultado, si no hay resultado procedo a guardar. Pero debo evitar guardarlos porque los dos registros ya ocupan ese periodo (2020-04-23 | 2020-04-30).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El rango será desde la menor fecha de inicio de la tabla, hasta la mayor fecha fin.

```
var r = from t1 in db.TblEtapa                                                                     
            where 
           (
            fechaInicio >= db.TblEtapa.Min(t => t.fecha_inicio) 
            && fechaFin <= db.TblEtapa.Max(t => t.fecha_fin)
            ) 
            select t1;
```